# What does a constructor return in Java?

Tags: java, constructor

After going on the post on this topic I found myself little confused.
So again I am asking this:

> "Does Java constructor returns any value?"

My books say they can't return a value, but my professor says they can and they are always doing so.

As the control needs to be transferred to someone with some value either void?

Comment: Maybe your professor meant they return a new instance ?

Comment: May be this helps: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5

Comment: 'As the control needs to be transferred to someone with some value either void?' is meaningless. Your professor is wrong. If you want to know what he means, you will have to ask him.

Comment: constructor does not have a return type, but they return a value. Its 'current class instance'

Answer (score 40):

This is a little confusing: constructors indeed do not return a value; it is operator `new` that does. However, constructors are always used with a `new`<sup>*</sup>, so it looks like they *always* return a value.

---

<sup>*</sup> This is a slight simplification: you can use a constructor without `new` if you go through *reflection*. However, the same mechanisms will be in play.

Comment: new is just a keyword so how it can return a value?

Comment: @shivdhwajpndey I did not say that `new` keyword returns a value: I said that the `new` *operator* does. Keywords and special characters are syntax elements; they don't do anything. It's the operators that they represent that do. Keyword `new` by itself is as meaningless as a `+` or `-` left by themselves. They need operands. Just like a unary minus takes one operand which must be a number, operator `new` takes one operand which must be a constructor. Operator `new` takes care of allocating the memory, calling the constructor, passing it the required parameters, and returning the value to you.

Comment: @user2040824 Where exactly does it say that keywords can't be associated with returning a value?

Comment: It is quite possible to call a constructor without the `new` keyword, and without using reflection. In the statements `this();` and `super();`, a constructor is invoked without a new object being created.

Comment: @kaya3 Both `this()` and `super()` are available only inside of a constructor of a related class. These are not proper invocations of a constructor, because they do not leave an object fully initialized upon completion.

Comment: According to the spec, `this()` is *"used to invoke an alternate constructor of the same class"* and `super()` is *"used to invoke a constructor of the direct superclass"*. I'm not sure what you mean by "proper invocation", but the spec describes both as "invocation", and they are called *"explicit constructor invocation statements"*.

Answer (score 8):

A constructor returns a new instance of the class it belongs to, even if it doesn't have an explicit return statement.

Comment: constructor if doesnt return anything then why this is used inside each constructor by compiler implicitly to return this.

Comment: @user2040824 It isn't used to 'return `this`'. It is used to *supply* the *value* of the current object. There is no 'return' about it.

Answer (score 8):

I think the confusion is purely notational. When you declare a constructor, you do it like so:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo() {}
}
```

Here, there's no explicit return value.

However, when you instantiate an object, the syntax is as follows:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

This creates a new object by allocating memory and calling the constructor. Here, the result is clearly an instance of `Foo`.

One way to reconcile the apparently conflicting notation is by thinking of a constructor as returning the object being constructed, but doing so implicitly.

Comment: But the compiler says else when checked it says this is returning from the constructor

Comment: @shivdhwajpandey `this` is the object being constructed.

Comment: @user2040824 No it doesn't. You're just making it up.

Answer (score 5):

Constructors are SPECIAL METHODS.
Well the Basic difference in Constructors and Methods is that

**Constructor**

- Have same name as that of Class
- does not have a return type
- Can be Overloaded but not Overridden.

whereas

**Methods**

- May or may not have same name as that of Class.
- have return type
- Can be Overloaded and Overridden.

**Syntax For Methods:**
AccessModifier ReturnType Class(...)
**EG:**  public static void main(String []args)

**Syntax For Constructors:**
AccessModifier *No ReturnType* Class(...)
**EG:**  public static main(String []args)

**Please Note:**

Java is a strongly typed language, so each function has its return type, and constructor always returns an instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

so, far i am concern constructor return the reference id to reference variable of that class. take an example:

```
class demo
{
    demo{}
}
class demo1
{
    public static void main(String as[])
    {
        demo d = new demo();
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

output: demo@7d4991ad
it is the reference id of the object 'd' of class demo which is returned by the constructor. if u will not define your constructor then jvm will get this id from default constructor.

you can cross check it by this line:
System.out.println(new demo());
output: demo@1b6d3586.
since every object has its separate heap area in memory so reference id of each object also vary.

Comment: Was it so difficult to indent the code a little to make it readable?

Answer (score 1):

As a Java programmer, one needs a mental model to predict the behaviour of Java programs, at both compile-time and at runtime. So long as one's mental model makes correct predictions compared with reality (i.e. compared with the behaviour the language specification describes, or compared with the behaviour of an actual Java implementation), then the mental model is *viable*. Two different, incompatible mental models may sometimes both be *viable*, and this is an example.

---

Here's what the language specification ([§15.9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4)) has to say:

> Next, the selected constructor of the specified class type is invoked. ...
>
> The value of a class instance creation expression is a reference to the newly created object of the specified class.

So the constructor is invoked, and the result of the expression invoking the constructor is a reference to the new object. The specification doesn't say that the constructor returns that reference, and it also doesn't say that the constructor *doesn't* return that reference.

---

Let's consider the *"constructor returns a reference to the new object"* mental model. It does make intuitive sense; when you invoke a constructor in a `new Object()` expression, the expression has a value much like when you invoke a method in a `foo.bar()` expression, the expression has a value. In the latter case, the expression's value is the method's return value, so it may be intuitively apppealing to say in the former case, the expression's value is the constructor's return value.

Now, it is a very *clunky* mental model, because you have to imagine that:

- Constructors end with an implicit `return this;`,
- Every bare `return;` in a constructor is implicitly `return this;`,
- The implicit `return this;` is only present when it's reachable, because the static checker (which does check implicit code, e.g. in default no-arg constructors) forbids unreachable code,
- The statements `this();` and `super();` are illegal when used as expressions, for a completely arbitrary reason.

The alternative mental model, that the constructor doesn't return anything, is a lot simpler, and is *viable* without any caveats. As an educator, I favour teaching this mental model due to its simplicity.

But as long as you are careful, then both mental models make identical predictions about the behaviour of Java programs. Philosophically speaking, it's a bit like different interpretations of quantum mechanics; as long as they all make the same predictions, then there is no scientific basis to say that a particular one is true and the others are false. Rather, the *"constructor doesn't return anything"* model is just simpler and easier to apply, so in my opinion it is more useful to learn and teach.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above two explanation , and want to add some statements to make more clear:

Question :  What is a constructor :
Answers: Its a method having name same as Class.

Question: Does constructor returns anything ?
Answer: No , not even VOID.

Question : How to call a constructor ? OR how does a constructor gets called ?
Answers : By creating an Object using NEW keyword.

Question: how to create object ?
Answer: One way of creating object is using NEW operator , that returns an instance of object.

Comment: constructor if doesnt return anything then why this is used inside each constructor by compiler implicitly to return this.

Comment: @user2040824 It isn't used to 'return `this`'. It is used to *supply* the *value* of the current object. There is no 'return' about it.

Comment: A constructor is not a method, according to the Java Language Specification; a method is a class member, but a constructor is not a class member. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html

Answer (score 0):

By definition there is no possibility of returning a value from a constructor.A constructor does not support any return type

Answer (score 0):

The constructor returns the reference id. 
i have made a little program to prove it

```
class Alpha {
    void myMethod() {
        System.out.println(this);// prints same reference ID
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Alpha alpha = new Alpha();
        System.out.println(alpha);// prints the reference ID
        alpha.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Output

```
Alpha@16f65612
Alpha@16f6512
```

you can clearly see that both reference ids are same

Answer (score -1):

Imagine yourself in a situation where you are told to sketch an Eagle.

First Scenario: You are not told how should it look. All you know is to make a simple sketch of an Eagle

Second Scenario: You are being told exactly what colors to use and the posture in which Eagle is to be sketched

Now the First scenario depicts exactly what an default constructor does and the Second scenario is when you have information as to HOW the object should be created. But until and unless you take a pencil and paper and start sketching you will not be returned anything.

So when you call the constructor using a new keyword you get an object. Though it doesnt explicitly return something but instead it creates or constructs something which you can use as an instance of a class.

Answer (score -1):

yes, it is the current class instance. (We cannot use return type yet it returns a value).

Comment: 1. 'It' being what? 2. Actually we *can* use the return type, via `this`, but it *doesn't* return a value.

Answer (score -3):

implicitly constructor return the class type........

Comment: Implicitly or explictly it doesn't return anything at all, and certainly not the 'class type'.