# Java: calling a method on a Constructor

Tags: java

Java constructors can't return a value. Why can then we still call an instance method on a constructor? E.g. why is `new Foo().bar()` legal where `bar()` is an instance method of class `Foo`?

Comment: You're not calling it on a constructor, you're calling it on the value resulting from a new instance creation expression.

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14737449/1291150

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the constructor doesn't return a value, the expression `new Foo()` does *evaluate* to an expression — namely, the reference value of the newly created object.

In fact, that's how `Foo var = new Foo()` works. There's nothing special going on there: you're declaring a new variable `var`, and assigning it to the result of some expression. It just so happens that evaluating that expression also creates a new object.

`new Foo().bar()` is equivalent to `(new Foo()).bar()`. It evaluates an expression (`new Foo()`), which at compile-time has a static type of `Foo`, and then performs an operation on the resulting value (invoking the `bar()` method).

In that regard, it's similar to `(a + b) * c`, which evaluates an expression (`(a + b)`) and then performs an operation on the resulting value (multiplying it by `c`).

Comment: Thx. So symbolically it is something like new(Foo()); and it's new() that returns the reference and not Foo().

Comment: No, `new Foo()` can't be broken down any more than that -- it's a special syntax, "new" followed by a class name, followed by parentheses as in a method call. You can no more separate it out as `new(Foo())` as you could declare an array as `int ( [4] )`.

Answer (score 2):

> Java constructors can't return a value. Why can then we still call an instance method on a constructor?

Constructor not returning anything here in the case `new Foo().bar()`. The method invoking on `Foo` class `bar()` returning something that you are capturing.

> Why it is legal to write new Foo().bar() ?

It's 100% legal, since it's equivalent to

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.bar();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the "new" keyword that instantiates the object, not the constructor and it is that object that you are calling foo from.  The constructor is just telling the compiler what must be done for the newly instantiated instance.

When you code: new Foo().bar();  the following happens.

- Create a **new** instance of **Foo**
- The instance will then call **Foo's Constructor**
- The instance is then returned.
- Now **bar()** is called for the returned instance.

Answer (score 0):

Java Constructor returns the instance of that class.
    'new Foo()' is creating object of Foo class and you are calling bar() method of that object.
So its completely legal!!