# "Constructor return value of current class instance" I can't understand this line.Can any one give a clear explanation with example?

Tags: java, constructor

From a site while learning java i saw that they write

> constructor can return value of current class instance.

I don't get that what they try to mean by current class instance.how constructor return it?If there if i find a good example with explanation than it will better for me to understand the line.

Comment: possible duplicate [what does a constructor return in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737420/what-does-a-constructor-return-in-java)

Comment: _current class instance_ means current class object.

Comment: Constructors are methods. But they are a bit special. they are called from a static context (via `new` operator) like static methods but have access to instance fields like member methods. They are restricted to return the instance they are setting up, wich it refered to as "current" in your statement.

Comment: That means when we write `Student obj = new Student()` via new key word constructor  return some value of that class @Timothy Truckle

Comment: yes, that's what it means exactly, but this knowledge will not affect your everyday work...

Comment: thanks @TimothyTruckle

Answer (score 0):

The only way how this makes (somehow) sense is the fact that code *calling* a constructor "receives" an instance of that class:

```
Foo fooInstance = new Foo();
```

But of course, within your constructor, you don't do anything in order to "return" that newly created object.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will understand what is the constructor and

> constructor can return value of current class instance.

```
 public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
        gear = startGear;
        cadence = startCadence;
        speed = startSpeed;
    }

Bicycle myBike = new Bicycle(30, 0, 8);
```

> new Bicycle(30, 0, 8) creates space in memory for the object and
>   initializes its fields.

```
public Bicycle() {
    gear = 1;
    cadence = 10;
    speed = 0;
}

Bicycle yourBike = new Bicycle();
```

> invokes the no-argument constructor to create a new Bicycle object
>   called yourBike.

Answer (score 0):

public Class Signin()
{

```
private readonly IwebDriver _driver;
```

public signin(IwebDriver driver)
       {
        _driver=driver;
       }

```
     public static signin NavigateTo(IwebDriver driver)
      {
       driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Pageurl);
       return new Signin(driver);
      }
```

the above class Signin Returns the instance of naviagation to the URL, here the constructor is assigned to the driver and the Driver will return the signin instance